# How can I check if the picture is fully loaded?

Tags: jquery, jcrop

One little question. How can I check if the picture in the Jcropbox is fully loaded?
I am a javascript beginner so I would be really thankful if someone can help.
Here is my code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   jQuery('#<%= imgPerson.ClientID %>').Jcrop({
       onChange: showPreview,
       onSelect: updateCoords,
       aspectRatio: 1,
       minSize: [60, 60],
       setSelect: [1, 1, 60, 60], 
       allowSelect: false
   });
});

function updateCoords(c) {
   jQuery('#<%= X.ClientID %>').val(c.x);
   jQuery('#<%= Y.ClientID %>').val(c.y);
   jQuery('#<%= W.ClientID %>').val(c.w);
   jQuery('#<%= H.ClientID %>').val(c.h);
};

function showPreview(coords) {
   var height = '<%= hdnimgHeight.ClientID %>';
   var height2 = $(height).value;
   var rx = 60 / coords.w;
   var ry = 60 / coords.h;

   $('#<%= imgPreview.ClientID %>').css({
       width: Math.round(rx * 400) + 'px',
       height: Math.round(ry * height2) + 'px',
       marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * coords.x) + 'px',
       marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * coords.y) + 'px'
   });
};
```

Comment: Your question's Javascript is contaminated with some server-side scripting language. Please fix.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Eh, the source code is good enough. The .NET tags show us accurately what he's doing. Leave the ASP.NET markup, skill2bereal.

Comment: @Jon: I cannot pass his code to my browser in order to do this research for him for free. Which reminds me, some HTML would help too. (And, more to the point, the .NET is quite simply irrelevant and _should be abstracted away_.)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Not necessarily. If the ASP.NET code is returning something that is breaking JavaScript formatting or something it would be relevant. If he just pasted the resulting HTML we would be confused if it's a typo in the question vs. in the code.

Comment: @Jon: Yes, it would be relevant, and that's why he should have abstracted away the ASP.NET _as an initial debugging step_ before even considering posting here. It would narrow down the issue to either ASP.NET or Javascript; a question on both at the same time is nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to `onload` event of image which gets triggered when the image is fully loaded in the browser. Try something like this

```
<img src=".." onload="javascript:alert('Image loaded');" />
//Here you can call any javascript method in the onload event
```

It also has other events like `onabort`, `onerror` etc in case you wish to handle them differently.

Comment: thank for you reply. hm maybe i forgot something to mention... jcrop should just load when the picture is fully loaded.